# Running Interpreter with nnapi delegete, causes the cpu usage spike during inference

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, yolo

I converted yolov8 trained on my dataset to tflite and ran it, and the results are fine, but the CPU usage jumps during inference.

These images show a comparison of running on nnapi and 4threads.

[nnapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeb1e.png)

[running four threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppsRl.png)

[nnapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyIZP.png)

[running four threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qciOh.png)

When using nnapi, the inference speed is indeed faster than 4 threads.
The inference is moved on the executor, but the screen freezes for a moment during inference.
Is this normal behavior?
Or did I do something wrong in the conversion process to tflite, I am not sure.

My conversion code is

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS
  ,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS
]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.compat.v1.lite.constants.FLOAT16]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("yolov8s-seg.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

My trained yolov8s model worked fine,
so something went wrong during exporting process.

(original).pt -> (with:yolov8/exporter).onnx -> saved_model -> tflite

```
# onnx to saved_model
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

onnx_model = onnx.load(yolov8s-seg.onnx")
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph("yolov8s-seg")
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry i am not here to answer, but i was wondering, how do you interpret the outputs of tflite model converted from yolov8s-seg.pt.
i am struggling to get masks, bbox, classes etc from the outputs of the tflite mode.
models runs fine, gives some output,
but the dimensions are something like `[1, 160, 160, 32] from output_details[1]['index'] which are supposed to be Mask protos 
and
[1,40,8400] fro output_details[0]['index'] which are supposed to be Coordinates of detected objects, class labels, and confidence score`

How do you make sense out of it ?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots, it seems that the average CPU usage is smaller with NNAPI path comparing with 4 threads CPU, but it has some spikes occasionally.

I could think of two potential causes:

1. Maybe you are repeatedly creating new TFLite Interpreter instance which triggers NNAPI re-initialize & compile the models.
2. The model is not fully delegated to NNAPI, leaving a sizable portion of the model running on TFLite CPU implementation.

It might be helpful to check NNAPI verbose logging for more details. To do that: `adb shell setprop debug.nn.vlog 1` then run the app for 10s, and `adb logcat -d`.